# php get number of comments lines in the code

Tags: php

I am writing a code for svn tracking system.I want to count the number of comments line has put by developer.

is there a php function to get number of lines between two characters?
I want to get lines count between /* and */

thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo count(explode("\n", trim($str)));`

Comment: If you want an idea of how many comments are in the code, just count the `/*` and the `//` (and the lines starting with `#`) - that will be approximate (since for instance `//` may be inside `/* ... */` or nested comments, strings etc...), but possibly close to reality. Otherwise to get the real count, you'll have to implement an automate reading a char at a time that takes into account strings start / end, nested comments, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to parse a PHP source file and then count the comments.

**Example**

```
$source = file_get_contents('source.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
$comments = array_filter($tokens, function($token) {
    return $token[0] === T_COMMENT;
});

echo "Number of comments: " . count($comments);
```

Note that this counts the number of comments, to count the number of lines you will have to count the line breaks in `$token[1]` (the actual comment) additionally.

**Update**

I wanted to try it out, here you go:

```
$source = <<<PHP
<?php
/*
 * comment 1
 */
function f() {
  echo 'hello'; // comment 2
  // comment 3
  echo 'hello'; /* OK, this counts as */ /* three lines of comments */ // because there are three comments
}
PHP;

$tokens = token_get_all($source);
$comments = array_filter($tokens, function($token) {
    return $token[0] === T_COMMENT;
});
$lines = array_reduce($comments, function(&$result, $item) {
    return $result += count(explode("\n", trim($item[1])));
}, 0);

echo "Number of comments: ", count($comments), "\n";
echo "Lines of comments: ", $lines;
```

**Output**

```
Number of comments: 6
Lines of comments: 8
```

**[Online Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/phn-u6c)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_replace` to remove everything between the `/* */` tags and then count the lines.

```
<?php
$string = <<<END
just a test with multiple line

/*
some comments

test
*/

and some more lines
END;

$lines = explode(chr(10), $string);
echo 'line count: ' . (count($lines)+1) . '<br>';
//line count: 10

$pattern = '/\/\*(.*)\*\//s';
$replacement = '';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);


$lines = explode(chr(10), $string);
echo 'line count: ' . (count($lines)+1);
//line count: 6
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you could try using the [PHP Reflection Library getDocComment()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php) however inline comments are probably not fetched.